# SQL query to identify all contacts without email address

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've created a SQL query to get me all unsubscribed contacts, but is there a query I can write to get all contacts without an email address into one data extension? There isn't a data view for contacts that I can find and all subscribers inherently have email addresses. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This help page has the best information '[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&language=en_US&type=1)'

> In MobileConnect or MobilePush, create a filtered mobile list that meets 4 conditions:
>
> Contact Key is not null AND Email Address is null AND Mobile Number is null AND Device ID is null ​
>
> Note: This is sourced from these attribute paths:
>
> System Data | Contact | Contact Key
>
> System Data | Email Addresses | Email Address
>
> MobileConnect Data | MobileConnect Demographics | Mobile Number
>
> MobilePush Data | MobilePush Demographics | Device ID
>
> This provides every record that does not belong to any channel (Contact Key with no source in All Contacts). Follow the below only if you need to review your data. Otherwise you can delete Mobile Filtered Lists using Contacts Delete.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to delete the records without email addresses/subkeys from the synchronized. Do you know how I would capture the other contacts without email address that are not from the synhcronized?